# Validation of object in array in java

Tags: java, string, validation, arraylist

How would I validate an array in one class using objects in another class.
I am doing a projects for a fishing tournament i have the species allowed in one class, but must do the catches in another.

```
#MAIN CLASS#
    Fish bass       = new Fish("Bass",      14, 20);
    Fish catfish    = new Fish("Catfish",   12, 30);
    Fish trout      = new Fish("Trout",     15, 12);
    Fish walleye    = new Fish("Walleye",   10, 15);
    fishList.add(bass);
    fishList.add(catfish);
    fishList.add(trout);
    fishList.add(walleye);






##class Fish##
 {
    //attributes:
    String speciesAllowed;
    double sizeLimit;
    int bagLimit;

//constructors:
Fish()
{
    speciesAllowed = " ";
    sizeLimit = 0.0;
    bagLimit = 0;

}// end constructor w/o argument
Fish(String speciesAllowed, double sizeLimit, int bagLimit)
{
    this.speciesAllowed = speciesAllowed;
    this.sizeLimit = sizeLimit;
    this.bagLimit = bagLimit;


}//end constructor w/ argument 

###class Tournament extends Fish###
{
//attributes:
String ssn;
String species;
double size;
int bag;
double weight;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------
//constructors
Tournament()
{
    super();
    ssn = " ";
    species = " ";
    size = 0.0;
    bag = 0;
    weight = 0.0;

}//end constructor w/0 argument
Tournament(String speciesAllowed, double sizeLimit, int bagLimit, String ssn, String species, double 
 size, int bag, double weight)
{
    super(speciesAllowed, sizeLimit, bagLimit);
    this.ssn = ssn;
    this.species = species;
    this.size = size;
    this.bag = bag;
    this.weight = weight;

}//end constructor w/ argument
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
void getCatch()
{
    String input = " ";
    boolean valid = false;
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter SSN: ");
    valid = checkSSN(input);
    while(!valid)
    {
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Invalid SSN...Please re-enter SSN: ");
        valid = checkSSN(input);
    }
    ssn = input;
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter species of the catch: ");
    //valid = checkSpecies(input);
    while(!valid)
    {
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Sorry that fish is not allowed ");
        //valid = checkSpecies(input);
    }
    species = input;
    //engHours = Integer.parseInt(input);
}//end getBOAT()
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
void dispTournament()
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SSN            : " + ssn       + "\n" +
                                        "Species        : " + species   + "\n" +
                                        "Size           : " + size      + "\n" +
                                        "Bag            : " + bag       + "\n" +
                                        "Weight         : " + weight    + "\n");
}//end dispTournament
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
boolean checkSSN(String input)
{
    if(input.length() != 9 )
        return false;
    else
        for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
        {
            if(!Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i)))
                return false;

        }
    return true;
boolean checkSpecies(String input)
{
    String allowed1 = "bass";
    String allowed2 = "trout";
    String allowed3 = "walleye";
    String allowed4 = "catfish";

    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    {
        if(input(i).equalsignorecase(<Fish>speciesAllowed))                 
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}//end checkSpecies
```

Wasn't sure how much was needed for help my problems are with the boolean checkSpecies. How would I compare it with the speciesAllowed from the Fish class. So that those are the only Fish a user could input.

And no this is not the whole program and this is just the snippets of what I need help with. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, there are only 4 possible species of `Fish` allowed:

```
Fish bass       = new Fish("Bass",      14, 20);
Fish catfish    = new Fish("Catfish",   12, 30);
Fish trout      = new Fish("Trout",     15, 12);
Fish walleye    = new Fish("Walleye",   10, 15);
```

And in `checkSpecies`, there is a user input validation.

```
boolean checkSpecies(String input)
{
    String allowed1 = "bass";
    String allowed2 = "trout";
    String allowed3 = "walleye";
    String allowed4 = "catfish";

    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    {
        if(input(i).equalsignorecase(<Fish>speciesAllowed))                 
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

There is no need to loop over `input`. I assume that `input` is fish, which must be validated. Instead you can check if `input` is present in allowed list for example:

```
return ALLOWED_SPECIES_LIST.contains(input.toLowerCase())
```

where `ALLOWED_SPECIES_LIST` might be something like
`Arrays.asList(allowed1,allowed2,allowed3,allowed4)` 
If you want to use defined `Fist`, there is already `fishList` which we might use:

```
return fishList.stream().map(Fish::speciesAllowed).anyMatch(input);
```

or without stream:

```
for(String fish: fishList) {
  if (fish.speciesAllowed.equals(input)){
     return true; 
  }
}
return false; 
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I do have a better understanding now and that definitely helped but I'm still not understanding completely.  The fish that I added to the fishList are the allowed species. The tournament class would take user input and i need to make sure that the species of Fish they enter equals one of those in the fishList. Hopefully this will clarify.  I had did the allowed1-4 in the checkSpecies as a way to just get it working so I know that can go completely

Comment: Here are my declared arrayList if this helps any.       static ArrayList<Fish>  fishList   = new ArrayList<Fish>();
    static ArrayList<Fisherman> fishermanList  = new ArrayList<Fisherman>();
    static ArrayList<Tournament> tournamentList = new ArrayList<Tournament>();